# Remove specific <script> tag in <head> tag by onclick event

Tags: javascript

```
<head>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function include(filename, status){
            if(status == 'on'){
                var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];

                script = document.createElement('script');
                script.src = filename;
                script.type = "text/javascript";

                head.appendChild(script);
            } else {
               // The code that wipes the script tag above
            }
        }

    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <input type="button" value="OPEN" onclick="include('script.js', 'on')">
    <input type="button" value="CLOSE" onclick="include('', 'off')">
</body>
```

I want to remove the specific  tag in  tag by onclick event.
What code should be written in the ELSE area, When I click the "CLOSE" botton?

Comment: Why do you want to remove script tag? In general, the javascript is read and digest by javascript engine on loading the script file, result even you remove that script tag from DOM later(in any event) will not remove the execution flow presented in removed script tag.

Comment: `head.removeChild(document.getElementById('script_id'));`, though it is not very useful, the script itself remains in the memory, despite of removing the element from the DOM.

Comment: There are [several posts](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[javascript]+%22remove+script%22) here in SO handling this issue...

Comment: Were you able to solve this problems using the posted solutions below, if so please accept the correct answer for the benefit of everybody in the SO community.

Answer (score 32):

The easiest way, would be to somehow maintain a link to the created element. For example, you could put the include function into a closure and have a private variable, to hold the reference:

```
var include = (function(){
   // the reference to the script
   var theScript;

   return function (filename, status){
     if(status == 'on'){
       // adding a script tag
       var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];

       theScript= document.createElement('script');
       theScript.src = filename;
       theScript.type = "text/javascript";

       head.appendChild( theScript )
     }else{
       // removing it again
       theScript.parentNode.removeChild( theScript );
     }
   }
})();
```

One important note: By removing the `<script>` tag, you do not remove any of its objects, functions etc. from the DOM. So any action started within that `<script>` tag will prevail, even if you delete the element, that started it in the first place!

Comment: Put `on` in quotes, otherwise it will raise exception.

Comment: Tried this code, seems to be working perfectly fine for me, but wondering why OP has not accepted it as the correct answer.

Comment: any solution to remove the script tag from dom, because i am using ajax to append data, they dont work without the scripts so in the fetch file i just added the scripts but by fetching the data, the script tag is multiply added and in one click it calls x times same function, if anyone can help me here out it would be gorgious: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51638466/ajax-after-fetch-data-loads-multiply-scripts

Answer (score 12):

You could also add an ID to the ScriptElement

this will work for you

```
function include(filename, status){
  if(status == "on"){
     var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];

     script = document.createElement('script');
     script.src = filename;
     script.type = "text/javascript";
     script.id = "testScriptName";

     head.appendChild(script);
  }else{
    (elem=document.getElementById("testScriptName")).parentNode.removeChild(elem)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using this:

```
function include(filename, status){
  var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
  if(status == on){
     script = document.createElement('script');
     script.src = filename;
     script.type = text/javascript;
     head.appendChild(script)
  }
  else if(status == 'off'){
     var scripts = head.getElementsByTagName('script');
     if(scripts.length > 0){
        head.removeChild(scripts[0]);
     }
  }
}
```