# How to conditionally include assets in the <head> with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am building a one-page Angular app. One of the views has content which depends on an external javascript library.

I don't want to include this external JS resource on every view of the site, just the single view which depends on it.

What is the best way to conditionally include  blocks of code based on the current view?

If it's possible I'm hoping I can place in the  something like this:

```
<script ng-if="view == 'view1'" type='text/javascript' src='http://webplayer.unity3d.com/download_webplayer-3.x/3.0/uo/UnityObject2.js'></script>
```

Comment: depends on what that script does.... does it require elements to exist when it loads?

Comment: @ZenDD angular will not run JS included in the view template. :-(

Comment: @charlietfl the external JS looks for a div included in the view template then injects a Unity plugin inside that div.

Comment: does it provide methods to manually trigger the code? Will have to put this in a directive in order for element to exist ... question then becomes is it the whole script or just initialization code within that directive

Comment: @charlietfl here is a link to the code I need to add to Angular:
https://gist.github.com/metaColin/09076a7904a52ffd2fef

Comment: Btw, there are some workarounds to use the scripts in templates. One of them is to have jQuery loaded before Angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you should include the library script in page.

Then within directive bound to elements it needs to act on do the initialization.

```
app.directive('unity', function () {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            // element is jQuery object when jQuery.js is included in page 
            // before angular - or it is a jQLite object similar to a jQuery object

            // config code

            u.initPlugin(element[0], "web_ovar_beta.unity3d");
        }
    }
});
```

Usage in view:

```
<div unity></div>
```

This can easily be expanded to pass in attributes to the directive from controller

Answer (score 1):

It is

```
<script ng-if="view == 'view1'" type='text/javascript' ng-src='http://webplayer.unity3d.com/download_webplayer-3.x/3.0/uo/UnityObject2.js'></script>
```

And it is something that you don't want to do. It doesn't guarantee that the script won't be loaded twice. Since the script is being used for particular view, make it one-time resolving service

```
app.factory('unityResolver', function ($document, $rootScope, $q, $timeout) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  var script = angular.element('<script>')[0]; 

  script.src = '...';
  script.async = true;
  script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (['loaded', 'complete', undefined].indexOf(script.readyState) < 0)
      return;

    script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = null;

    deferred.resolve();
    $rootScope.$apply();
  }

  script.onerror = function onerror() {
    script.onerror = null;

    deferred.reject();
    $rootScope.$apply();
  };

  $timeout(onerror, 20000);
  $document.find('head').append(script);

  return deferred.promise;
});
```

and use it in view/route `resolve`.

Answer (score -1):

What your wanting to in turn is impossible.

You can get Javascript to include a javascript file if you want however if your using AJAX to load the content that is needed leave it in there it would be the same amount of time to load anyway. but once a file has been loaded into JavaScript it finished with you can remove the file from your HTML but the JavaScript engine still has the content of that file loaded in to it.

Try it in your browsers(chrome or FF with Firebug) inspector now:
open a new tab and go to `about:blank` then put the code below into the console

```
var include = (function(){
   // the reference to the script
   var theScript;

   return function (filename, status){
     if(status == 'on'){
       // adding a script tag
       var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];

       theScript= document.createElement('script');
       theScript.src = filename;
       theScript.type = "text/javascript";

       head.appendChild( theScript )
     }else{
       // removing it again
       theScript.parentNode.removeChild( theScript );
     }
   }
})();
```

taken from [Remove specific <script> tag in <head> tag by onclick event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14708189/remove-specific-script-tag-in-head-tag-by-onclick-event)

then in your inspector's console

```
include("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js", 'on')
```

now check Elements and you will see jQuery loaded in the pages head tag.
and type `jQuery`into console and you will see `function (a,b){return new n.fn.init(a,b)}`

And then use this into your console

```
include("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js", 'off')
```

and check your elements tab again the script tag will have gone.
however go back to console and type `jQuery` again and you will see `function (a,b){return new n.fn.init(a,b)}` as even though you have unloaded the file you can't remove the executed code from memory.

You have 2 options another framework page gets loaded into an iFrame or if you want to use Anagular to load the View in then just include the file in your head there is no point not having and then removing it as once it is loaded it's loaded

Comment: not sure why you say it is impossible ... that's not true

Comment: thats what the `in turn` bit means as in the end result adding and removing `<script...>` html is possible i have the code for it in my answer but `in turn` why would you want to remove a script tag from your html once it is loaded? if it was not to remove it from memory which is impossible

Comment: I downvoted because: Poor english (to the point of misunderstanding), and also a brute-force solution that does not actually leverage Angular.

Comment: OMG what do you think AngularJS is, it's Javascript. it's not brute force to use Javascript with more javascript but this is not a solution your end result is impossible and i explained why just coz you don't know how your browser uses a Javascript Framework. that's like saying ASP.NET does not use HTML.

But back to Javascript the good thing with using Standard Javascirpt is it work independent of Frameworks hell if you wanted i could make it so it was a plugin of angular it still proves the point the end result you are wanting is impossible.