# Cannot find module when importing with SystemJs in Angular

Tags: angular, system, systemjs, aot, systemjs-builder

I'm trying to import an external module with SystemJs in Angular doing

```
    import { System } from 'systemjs';
    declare const SystemJS: System;

...

    SystemJs.import('./assets/example/example.js').then(m=>{
      console.log('the module is', m);
    });
```

I also tried with http://localhost:4200/assets/example/example.js

The js file is there and accessible.

But I'm getting an error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find module 'http://localhost:4200/assets/example/example.js'
```

I tried it in a clean project and it works fine, so I think the problem can be related to some angular specific configuration.

Any clue about what can be wrong?

Comment: Does this help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35898339/how-could-i-use-a-system-import-into-component-angular-2

Comment: Is this file placed at path that you've specified if you navigate in that folder after build?

Comment: @Ostn, no it doesn't, but thank you

Comment: @Sergey, yes, it is, I can navigate to the assets or to the uri and I'm able to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you configure SystemJS?

Like this:

```
System.config({
  baseURL: './src/app',

  // Set paths your modules
  paths: {
    'example': 'assets/example/example.js'
  }
});

SystemJs.import('example').then(m=>{
  console.log('the module is', m);
});
```