# Angular 2: import external js file into component

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack

I'm going to import this [d3gauge.js](https://github.com/oliverbinns/d3gauge) file into one of my angular2 component, `memmon.component.ts` file.

```
import '../../../../js/d3gauge.js';
export class MemMonComponent {
    createMemGauge() {
        new drawGauge(this.opt);  //drawGauge() is a function inside d3gauge.js
    }
}
```

and in the corresponding template file, add

```
<script src="../../../../js/d3gauge.js"></script>
```

But it doesn't work, `drawGauge`can't be found.

So,

1. what're correct steps to import an external js file to angular2?
2. since I'm using webpack, is it possible to do it in webpack? I refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34489916/load-external-js-script-dynamically-in-angular-2) , the webpack solution there doesn't work for me as a result of `.ensure` can't be resolved.

Comment: you need to create or import typings (*.d.ts) for the file.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Ideally you need to have `.d.ts` file for typings to let `Linting` work.

But It seems that `d3gauge` doesn't have one, you can Ask the developers to provide and hope they will listen.

---

Alternatively, you can solve this specific issue by doing this

```ts
declare var drawGauge: any;

import '../../../../js/d3gauge.js';
export class MemMonComponent {
    createMemGauge() {
        new drawGauge(this.opt);  //drawGauge() is a function inside d3gauge.js
    }
}
```

---

If you use it in multiple files, you can create a `d3gauage.d.ts` file with the content below

```ts
declare var drawGauge: any;
```

and reference it in your `boot.ts` (bootstrap) file at the top, like this

```ts
///<reference path="../path/to/d3gauage.d.ts"/>
```

Comment: Thanks. One more question, when will the `declare var drawGauge: any;` be referenced, at the moment of transpile this ts file? Or, put it in another way, when  `new drawGauge(this.opt)` , how does the compiler know the `drawGauge()` is actually in `d3gauge.js`?

Comment: Yes, on transpile, it has to know that there is/ or will be something named `d3gauge`. In second question, it doesn't, `d3gauge.js` assigns it to a `global` variable in the `dom` and that is from where it's being called on  runtime.

Comment: I got `ReferenceError: drawGauge is not defined`. Is it because I'm using webpack?

Comment: just put `<script src="../../../../js/d3gauge.js"></script>` in your `index.html` only, nowhere else, webpack solution probably doesn't work because of wrong path, but i don't know anything about `webpack`

Comment: @BingLu Hey man, did you get the solution working for you? I still got the `EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in someComponent` saying that the declared variable `is not defined` and could not find a solution so far.

Comment: do you need to declare a variable for every function that you use in a particular js file? that can get crazy when there are a lot of functions.

Comment: what is boot.ts did you mean app.component.ts

also i don't how to add 

///<reference path="../path/to/d3gauage.d.ts"/>
in app.component.ts

Answer (score 56):

After wasting a lot of time in finding its solution, **I've found one**. For your convenience I've used the complete code that you can replace your whole file with.

This is a general answer. Let's say you want to import a file named testjs.js into your angular 2 component.
Create testjs.js in your assets folder:

**assets > testjs.js**

```
function test(){
    alert('TestingFunction')
}
```

include testjs.js in your index.html

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Project1</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">

  <script src="./assets/testjs.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

In your app.component.ts or in any component.ts file where you want to call this js declare a variable and call the function like below:

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

declare var test: any;


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';


  f(){
    new test();
  }
}
```

Finally in your **app.component.html** test the function

**app.component.html**

```
<h1>
  <button (click)='f()'>Test</button>
</h1>
```

Comment: do we need to declare the function name on component, what if i have many functions do I need to declare all? Also its not working i am getting these errors "ERROR ReferenceError: test is not defined" and  "Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:4200/assets/custom.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled."

Answer (score 15):

Instead of including your `js` file extension in `index.html`, you can include it in `.angular-cli-json` file.

These are the steps I followed to get this working:

1. First include your external `js` file in `assets/js`
2. In `.angular-cli.json` - add the file path under scripts:
   `[../app/assets/js/test.js]`
3. In the component where you want to use the functions of the `js` file.

Declare at the top where you want to import the files as

```
declare const Test:any;
```

After this you can access its functions as for example `Test.add()`

Comment: Hi, can you tell me where to put the part "Declare const Test:any;" ? Inside the component? I tried to put it inside the export class, and also before the "export class...." but it didn't work.

Comment: In your app.component.ts or in any component.ts file where you want to call the method of Test, just add "Declare const Test:any" at the top where you import other dependencies of that component.

Comment: `declare` not `Declare`

Answer (score 6):

The following approach worked in Angular 5 CLI.

For sake of simplicity, I used similar d3gauge.js demo created and provided by oliverbinns - which you may easily find on Github.

So first, I simply created a new folder named ***externalJS*** on same level as the ***assets*** folder. I then copied the 2 following .js files.

- d3.v3.min.js
- d3gauge.js

I then made sure to declare both linked directives in main ***index.html***

```
<script src="./externalJS/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="./externalJS/d3gauge.js"></script>
```

I then added a similar code 
in a ***gauge.component.ts*** component as followed:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

declare var d3gauge:any; <----- !
declare var drawGauge: any; <-----!

@Component({
  selector: 'app-gauge',
  templateUrl: './gauge.component.html'
})

export class GaugeComponent implements OnInit {
   constructor() { }

   ngOnInit() {
      this.createD3Gauge();
   }

   createD3Gauge() { 
      let gauges = []
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {      
      let opt = {
         gaugeRadius: 160,
         minVal: 0,
         maxVal: 100,
         needleVal: Math.round(30),
         tickSpaceMinVal: 1,
         tickSpaceMajVal: 10,
         divID: "gaugeBox",
         gaugeUnits: "%"
    } 

    gauges[0] = new drawGauge(opt);
    });
 }
```

}

and finally, I simply added a div in corresponding gauge.component.html

```
<div id="gaugeBox"></div>
```

et voilà ! :)

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Here is a simple way i did it in my project.

lets say you need to use `clipboard.min.js` 
and for the sake of the example lets say that inside `clipboard.min.js` there is a function that called `test2()`.

in order to use test2() function you need:

1. make a reference to the .js file inside you index.html.
2. import `clipboard.min.js` to your component.
3. declare a variable that will use you to call the function.

here are only the relevant parts from my project (see the comments):

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Angular QuickStart</title>
    <base href="/src/">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="/node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>


    <script src="/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
        System.import('main.js').catch(function (err) { console.error(err); });
    </script>

    <!-- ************ HERE IS THE REFERENCE TO clipboard.min.js -->
    <script src="app/txtzone/clipboard.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <my-app>Loading AppComponent content here ...</my-app>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.component.ts:**

```
import '../txtzone/clipboard.min.js';
declare var test2: any; // variable as the name of the function inside clipboard.min.js

@Component({
    selector: 'txt-zone',
    templateUrl: 'app/txtzone/Txtzone.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['app/txtzone/TxtZone.css'],
})



export class TxtZoneComponent implements AfterViewInit {

    // call test2
    callTest2()
    {   
        new test2(); // the javascript function will execute
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

For `.js` files that expose more than one variable (unlike `drawGauge`), a better solution would  be to set the Typescript compiler to process `.js` files.

In your `tsconfig.json`, set `allowJs` option to true:

```
"compilerOptions": {
     ...
    "allowJs": true,
     ...
}
```

Otherwise, you'll have to declare each and every variable in either your `component.ts` or `d.ts`.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try this:

```
import * as drawGauge from '../../../../js/d3gauge.js';
```

and just `new drawGauge(this.opt);` in your ts-code. This solution works in project with angular-cli embedded into laravel on which I currently working on. In my case I try to import `poliglot` library (btw: very good for translations) from node_modules:

```
import * as Polyglot from '../../../node_modules/node-polyglot/build/polyglot.min.js';
...
export class Lang 
{
    constructor() {

        this.polyglot = new Polyglot({ locale: 'en' });
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

This solution is good because i **don't need to COPY** any files from `node_modules` :) .

## UPDATE

You can also look on [this LIST](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50516233/860099) of ways how to include libs in angular.

Comment: Worked for me :)

Answer (score 1):

1) First Insert JS file path in an **index.html** file :

`<script src="assets/video.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

2) Import JS file and declare the variable in **component.ts** :

- import  './../../../assets/video.js';
- declare var **RunPlayer**: any;

  **NOTE:** Variable name should be same as the name of a function in js file

3) Call the js method in the component

```
ngAfterViewInit(){

    setTimeout(() => {
        new RunPlayer();
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have added a file "xyz.js" under *assets/js* folder in some *Angular* project in *Visual-Studio*, then the easiest way to include that file is to add it to **.angular-cli.json**

```
"scripts": [ "assets/js/xyz.js" ],
```

You should be able to use this JS file's functionality in your component or .ts files.

Comment: But for a big app, it would not be ideal to list all the scripts there because some of these scripts will never be used because they are meant only for specific components.

Comment: how can we use ?