# Including custom none npm js files into angular 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

The application I build at the moment runs in an `angular 2.0.0 final` environment using typescript. Furthermore it uses the `angular-cli 1.0.0-beta.15`.

As the whole application is produced by several different developers (all using `typescript`) I get some `.js` files that are compiled from `typescript` and should be included and used in my angular 2 app.

My problem however is, that I can't seem to find a way to integrate the `.js` file and use it in e.g. a component.

I allready checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37081943/angular2-import-external-js-file-into-component) SO question as well as [this](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/issues/570) question in the official repo but neither of these answers worked for me.

I even tried a workaround where I include the `.js` file globally in the `angular-cli.json` like this:

```
"scripts": [
    "../path/to/custom.js"
]
```

How can I (generally and specifically for this scenario) include custom .js files which do not come as e.g. `npm` module or have any `d.ts` files.

**EDIT:**

The including itself by using the `angular-cli.json` seems to work well but for now I still could not find a way to use the scripts methods. Whenever I do

```
declare var customJsObject: any;
```

It throws an

```
EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): 
Error: Error in CustomComponent caused by: customJsObject is not defined
```

Comment: Are you shore that path is correct? The file path shoud work relatively to the root path set in angular-cli.json

Comment: @Illorian yeah I'm sure. the folder structure is `src/app/assets/custom.js` the defined root is `src` and the import path in the `angular-cli.json`'s scripts array is `./app/assets/custom.js` but still i get a 404

Comment: Oh, I understand. Do you try to remove in path *app*?

Comment: @Illorian this results in an angular-cli error: `Error: Can't resolve currently/used/path/to/custom.js in path/to/angular-cli/models`

Comment: The error is throwing by ts compiler or browser?

Comment: by the compiler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my project:

```
{
"project" : {
    "version": "1.0.0-beta.15",
    "name"   : "my-project"
},
"apps"    : [
    {
        "root"        : "src",
        "outDir"      : "dist",
        "assets"      : "assets",
        "index"       : "index.html",
        "main"        : "main.ts",
        "test"        : "test.ts",
        "tsconfig"    : "tsconfig.json",
        "prefix"      : "",
        "mobile"      : false,
        "styles"      : [
            "sass/application.scss",
            "assets/fonts/bebas/bebasneue.css"
        ],
        "scripts"     : [
            "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
            "../node_modules/fastclick/lib/fastclick.js",
            "../node_modules/jquery.cookie/jquery.cookie.js",
            "../node_modules/jquery-placeholder/jquery.placeholder.js",
            "../node_modules/foundation-sites/dist/foundation.js",
            "../node_modules/jquery-ui/ui/version.js",
            "../node_modules/jquery-ui/ui/plugin.js",
            "../node_modules/jquery-ui/ui/widget.js",
            "../node_modules/jquery-ui/ui/widgets/mouse.js",
            "../node_modules/jquery-ui/ui/widgets/draggable.js",
            "assets/rollbar.js"
        ],
        "environments": {
            "source": "environments/environment.ts",
            "dev"   : "environments/environment.ts",
            "prod"  : "environments/environment.prod.ts"
        }
    }
],
"addons"  : [],
"packages": [],
"e2e"     : {
    "protractor": {
        "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
},
"test"    : {
    "karma": {
        "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
},
"defaults": {
    "styleExt"        : "scss",
    "prefixInterfaces": false
}
}
```

**Solution Edit:**

For this specific problem there was a naming issue which caused the problem. In general the provided answer "entering the script in the `angular-cli.json`" was correct.

The only thing one need to do afterwards is

```
declare var customJsObject: any;
```

in the component you want to use the `custom.js` in.

Comment: I got that part and it seams to work as the component itself is displaying and not throwing any errors. But how can I use this script? I tried to use a hack where I `declare var customJsObject: any` in the component but whenever I want to use a method on that object it just replies with `EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in customComponent caused by: customJsObject is not defined`

Comment: Do you use module.exports in custom.js?

Comment: No. As it is a compiled file as described above it's a structure like

`var Custom;`
`(function(Custom){
  Custom.prototype.foo = function() {
    this.bar = baz
  }
})`

Comment: @Mr.Moe, try to add this script into index.html.If you still have an error then problem in file. Otherwise you should to export your data from file

Comment: I didnt get what you mean with your last sentence, sorry.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/custom.js">

Put it into your index.html. If you still have an error then problem in file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124503/discussion-between-mr-moe-and-illorian).