# How to use any Javascript file in angular 2?

Tags: angular, webpack

I want to use JavaScript file in angular 2. For Example, I have "multi-select" JavaScript file, which I can used simply doing `$(".select2_demo_1").select2();` in html page. But i want to use this JavaScript file in angular 2. Is there any way to use this JavaScript or need to use it's angular 2 version?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bangular2%5D+javascript+library

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2: import external js file into component](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37081943/angular2-import-external-js-file-into-component)

Answer (score 0):

Angular 2 supported JS code.

Example:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

declare var $:any;

@Component({
    selector: 'navigation',
    templateUrl: 'navigation.template.html'
})

export class NavigationComponent {

    constructor(private router: Router) {}

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        $('#side-menu').metisMenu();
    }
}
```

1. `declare var $:any;` --> declare jquery
2. `$('#side-menu').metisMenu();` --> jquery code