# Routing in angular disables javascript functions

Tags: javascript, angular, routes

I have a simple angular routing module that looks like this:

```
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './../../home/home.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './../../login/login.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

The HomeComponent is loaded at first whenever I open the page. everything works fine until I switch to the login page. Both of them have certain parts that work with javascript. I added those in the .angular-cli.json file.

If I switch to the login page using the following button:

```
<li class="active"><a routerLink="">Home</a></li>
```

none of those functions seem to work, also whenever I switch back to the homepage component, the functions that did work before won't work here either.

So far i found out that the scripts are loaded once since the main application is loaded using "eager loading" and the compontens use "lazy loading".

Is there a way to load the scripts again or any other way to fix this?

Comment: Without seeing your JavaScript I recon it's because probably you use the document load listener to trigger your JS. Angular only loads a page once, after that the document load event won't fire anymore until you do a full refresh of the page.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the problem by using the solution given on the following page:

[how to load js on component level in angular 4. I don't want to load all js file at app startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45861526/how-to-load-js-on-component-level-in-angular-4-i-dont-want-to-load-all-js-file)

given by Milad.