# Adding external JS script with defer attribute to Angular 11 project

Tags: javascript, angular, deferred

I would like to use an [external JS library](https://webgate.ec.europa.eu/fpfis/wikis/display/webtools/Webtools+documentation+-+Homepage?src=breadcrumbs-parent) into my Angular 11 project created using the Angular-CLI.

From many answers ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46034627/1979665), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44204736/1979665), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41121613/1979665)), I see that one way to achieve this is by adding the path to the JS file into the `scripts` section of `angular.json` file, and add variable declarations in typings.d.ts file (I should create one if it does not exist).

However, I would like to be able to load it with a "defer" attribute, namely when the page has finished parsing, as [in the documentation of this library](https://webgate.ec.europa.eu/fpfis/wikis/display/webtools/Widgets#Widgets-1.Includetheloaderscript) it reads:

> Don't forget the defer attribute. It reduces the loading time of your
> page.

From [the official Angular docs page on this section](https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#styles-and-scripts-configuration), there does not seem to be an option to add this attribute, and I don't understand when these external libraries are loaded. I was wondering if anyone can help me understanding this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can add anything you like into the `index.html`. Even a script with `defer` attribute.

Whether that is the best way to include the script into your project is up to you.