# How to load the script file immediately (dynamically added) before continue?

Tags: angular, typescript, sleep, script-tag

I have loaded script file like below code  in angular home.component.ts file

```
export class HomeComponent {
    constructor() {
        this.loadDynmicallyScript();
    } 
     public loadDynmicallyScript() {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = "../node_modules/xxxxxx/i18n/xx.min.js";
        script.async =false;
        document.head.appendChild(script);

     }
```

But this file gets loaded after components created and later. So, in this case, it makes no use of this file. I want to load this file once I appended in documents. How to achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load script file dynamically in app.component.ts(angular)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48973822/how-to-load-script-file-dynamically-in-app-component-tsangular)

Comment: i marked that question as duplicate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can return a promise to chain calls

```
export class HomeComponent {
    constructor() {
        this.loadDynmicallyScript()
        .then(() => {
          this.doSomethingWhenScriptIsLoaded();
        });
    } 
     public loadDynmicallyScript():Promise {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = "../node_modules/xxxxxx/i18n/xx.min.js";
        script.async =false;
        document.head.appendChild(script);
        return Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          script.onload = resolve;
        });    
     }
```

or just pass a function to the `onLoad` to be called when the script was loaded

```
export class HomeComponent {
    constructor() {
        this.loadDynmicallyScript()
    } 
     public loadDynmicallyScript():Promise {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = "../node_modules/xxxxxx/i18n/xx.min.js";
        script.async =false;
        document.head.appendChild(script);
        script.onload = () => this.doSomethingWhenScriptIsLoaded();
     }
```

Comment: Is it really possible to load a script from *node_modules* at runtime with a prod build? I have never thought to try, so I am curious.

Comment: Good point. I didn't even check the path in the question. I guess it depends on what the build step does exactly. He might need to provide the method somewhere else.

Comment: Hi,is this possible to make wait instead of calling the function(doSomethingWhenScriptIsLoaded)

Comment: No, this is happening in the UI thread. If the browser would wait, the whole UI would completely block until the script is loaded from the server and parsed and executed. That would lead to horrible user experience.

Comment: ok thanks, Gunter I will follow your above suggestion. Also, i saw the discussion with you and Richards. Am I doing anything wrong?. I am new to this and cannot understand that discussion.

Comment: The file `../node_modules/...` might exist during development, but not exist in the build output directory. I'm not using TypeScript myself so I don't know for sure. You might need to copy the script file to some assets directory or similar that is copied to the build output. I assume all imported files from `../node_modules` are just compiled to one or a few `xxx.js` files and the rest is ignored.

Comment: in order to access node_modules/any file on production, just add it to `assets` section in `.angular-cli` JSON file: "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico",
        {
          "glob": "xx.min.js",
          "input": "../node_modules/xxxxxx/i18n/xx.min.js",
          "output": "./assets/"
        }
      ], then on production the file will be available under /assets/xx.min.js