# How to load js files from Angular assets folder to specific Angular(2,4,5) component or module?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, typescript-typings

I have custom1.js, custom2.js, custom3.js JS files and load these files into Angular component1,component2,component3 respectively. I can add these files to the index.html files but Don't want to load these files globally.

Need to load these files component specific. Also, I went throw this Stackoverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44204417/dynamically-load-external-javascript-file-from-angular-component/44276683#44276683) but not getting exactly way to solve this problem. Is there any other ways to solve this problem.?

Thank in advance.

Comment: You have problem with AngularJS, or Angular2?

Comment: @KrzysztofRaciniewski
As per my knowledge Angular means Angular 2,4,5 which works with Typescript as well as Javascript and AngularJS means AngularJS (v1) which works with only Javascript.
  
Still, I update the question.

Comment: This would depend on what the contents of your custom.js file is. Loading a file, even in a component would load it globaly if you don't take the correct precautions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to add the js files to your angular-cli.json and then import them into each component as needed at the top of the component.ts file as follows

```
declare const custom1: any
```

Comment: I already try this but facing custome1.js is not module.
It would be great if you can give the detailed example.

Comment: in custome1.js you would bind your function to window.custome1, this would allow it to be accessible then