# Angular 6 videojs-record results in runtime error

Tags: angular, webpack, angular6, video.js, angular-webpack

I am using Angular 6 along with videojs-record plugin. I configured following dependencies in my project.

```
npm install --save video.js
npm install --save videojs-record
```

Later I referenced the videojs plugin using the following import statement.

```
import videojs from 'video.js';
import 'webrtc-adapter';
import RecordRTC from 'recordrtc';
import Record from 'videojs-record/dist/videojs.record.js';
```

While there is no error reported at the time of compilation, when I hit the browser I get following error in console.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined
    at Object../node_modules/webrtc-adapter/src/js/adapter_core.js (adapter_core.js:13)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:78)
    at Module../src/app/app.component.ts (main.js:93)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:78)
    at Module../src/app/app.module.ts (app.component.ts:13)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:78)
    at Module../src/main.ts (main.ts:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:78)
    at Object.0 (main.ts:12)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:78)
```

Please let me know, what I am missing here?

**Version Information:**

```
"video.js": "^7.2.3",
"videojs-record": "^2.4.1",
"@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
"@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
```

**UPDATE-1:**
If I change webrtc-adapter import from

```
import 'webrtc-adapter'
```

to

```
import 'webrtc-adapter/out/adapter_no_global.js';
```

videojs fails with the following error.

```
ERROR Error: plugin "record" does not exist
    at Player.<anonymous> (video.es.js:19615)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at new Player (video.es.js:19611)
    at videojs$1 (video.es.js:24059)
    at AppComponent.push../src/app/app.component.ts.AppComponent.startRecording (app.component.ts:43)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (AppComponent.html:5)
    at handleEvent (core.js:10251)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:11344)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:11047)
    at dispatchEvent (core.js:7710)
```

**UPDATE-2:**

I tried using angular cli customizer (https://github.com/nfriend/angular-cli-customizer) and followed instructions specified in https://github.com/collab-project/videojs-record/wiki/Angular

Unfortunately that too didn't work :(

Comment: did you install webrtc-adapter?

Comment: I didn't install it exclusively, but it is present in node_modules directory. I guess it downloaded due to transitive dependency.

Comment: this looks like you are using the master version instead of one of the versions published on NPM. Try the npm version, this might be a bug in master.

Comment: I am using following versions - "video.js": "^7.2.3",
    "videojs-record": "^2.4.1",

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but I solved it by using the below methodology,
Your **"videojs-record/dist/videojs.record.js"** file is not loading on that particular component so please try loading it **dynamically from the component.ts** file

For more reference see below link
[Dynamically load external javascript file from Angular component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44204417/dynamically-load-external-javascript-file-from-angular-component)