# Need to Call External JS file in angular in particular js in particular page

Tags: angular

I have .js file in my project
I've created angular project as partial view,So I need to include js file in particular page,
I need to call js file in angular 6 , angular.json is global declaration, So I need to include in this page only

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to call javascript function from the User.js in user.component.ts?

You can import javascript file as 
import * as abc from "./User.js";

and then call your function like abc.Yourfunction();

Hopefully, it 'll work for you

Comment: No, I need to call User.js file into user.html , I've called <script src="./User.js"></script> but not working for me

Comment: Can you try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44204417/dynamically-load-external-javascript-file-from-angular-component/44276683#44276683