# Dropbox embedder in Angular 12

Tags: angular, dropbox

I want to show [dropbox embedder](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/embedder) inside of an Angular component. I was able to show it, but it only works without guards and refreshing the browser after navigate to the component.

```
 this.router.navigate(['/files']).then(() => {
        window.location.reload();
      });
```

I included Dropbox embedder script in index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Dropbox files</title>
        <base href="/" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
        <link
          href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
          rel="stylesheet"
        />
        <script
          type="text/javascript"
          src="https://www.dropbox.com/static/api/2/dropins.js"
          id="dropboxjs"
          data-app-key="dropboxkey"
        ></script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <app-root></app-root>
      </body>
    </html>
```

And files component only has Dropbox embedder code

```
<a
  href="https://www.dropbox.com/sh/rsc2ecvsiyacmfe/iuiuhjhjhkjkjhkjhkjh_e9a?dl=0"
  class="dropbox-embed"
  data-height="100vh"
  >Folder</a
>
```

I wonder if there is another way to use embedder without page refreshing and angular guards. I do not want to use Dropbox API because embedder is perfect in my situation.

Thanks!

Edit: I was able to load JS file using [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50674496/5345343)

Now it only works first time the component loads, if you navigate to another component and navigate back to files console shows

```
zone.js:182 Uncaught Error: iframe does not contain a contentWindow
    at VM4414 dropins.js:2
    at t (VM4414 dropins.js:2)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:406)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:178)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:487)
    at invokeTask (zone.js:1600)
    at globalZoneAwareCallback (zone.js:1637)
```