# angular import .js library

Tags: angular, import

I am trying to add .js file ( [this](https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/blob/master/markerclustererplus/src/markerclusterer.js) )  to angular project. 
I tried `import * as abc from './marker-clusterer.js';` but `console.log` gave me an empty object. Any ideas?

Comment: check this out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37081943/angular2-import-external-js-file-into-component

Comment: I dont actualy get it :/.

Comment: ideally, you'd want a type definition file for the module you are trying to use as I believe you are working with angular2 and typescript. try using the absolute path to file? something like '../../node_modules/googleMaps/src/marker-clusterer.js' for example.

Comment: yes. I have file marker-clusterer.js (not in node_modules but it does not batter). But i dont understand how where should I add this file (.d.ts) and what this file should have to make this library working...

Comment: Try using the typescript compiler with the --traceResolution flag to get module resolution log.

Info here:
https://blog.angularindepth.com/configuring-typescript-compiler-a84ed8f87e3

and here:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html

Answer (score 0):

Install type definitions for google maps from 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/googlemaps

Verify that you have actual google maps module installed because type definition files are just empty shells. If you have not, here is a link. 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/googlemaps

And then import marker-clusterer.ts from `@types/googlemaps/"the path to index.d.ts"`

Comment: I already have google maps. I just need include the file I wrote in question

Comment: what i want is to add this https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/blob/master/markerclustererplus/src/markerclusterer.js ... it is not part of google maps ... i need to add it ... :(