# How to use amazon connect streams in Angular 5

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services

I want to get contact details using amazon connect streams, I am not aware how to use it in angular5. I searched throughly and I get the below js code. how to use it in angular5.

```
  connect.core.initCCP(containerDiv, {
     ccpUrl:        ccpUrl,        /*REQUIRED*/
     loginPopup:    true,          /*optional, default TRUE*/
     softphone:     {              /*optional*/
        disableRingtone:  true,    /*optional*/
        ringtoneUrl: ringtoneUrl   /*optional*/
     }
  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can refer to this solution:
[Angular2: import external js file into component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37081943/angular2-import-external-js-file-into-component)

Just to summarize this:
1. Add the .js file into assets folder of Angular.

2. Declare js file as script source tag in index.html
3. Then add "declare var connect: any;" in the component .ts file:

You should be able to call the functions in js file from the component typescript

Hope this helps!