# How to import javascript files in a particular component like Html and css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular

`

```
<script src="./jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Core plugin JavaScript-->
  <script src="./jquery.easing.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Page level plugin JavaScript-->
  <script src="./Chart.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  <script src="./dataTables.bootstrap4.js"></script>

  <!-- Custom scripts for all pages-->
  <script src="./sb-admin.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Demo scripts for this page-->
  <script src="./datatables-demo.js"></script>
  <script src="./chart-area-demo.js"></script>
```

This is the some part of code of my index.html file in an angular component.I want to import all the js files as above but couldn't be able to do that.Can anyone please tell that how i can include all the javascripts file?I only just want to include it in Html file of an angular component.I can't do it globally as i have to use it only in a particular Component

Comment: Are you trying to use these js files in your typescript code ?

Comment: No I am not using  it in my typescript code.

Comment: You should usually, import scripts via your angular.json file.

Comment: Another issue might be the path from where you are referencing the js files, Make sure they exist at the location you have specified. "./xyx.js" implies it should be no the same level as the file it was refered in.

Comment: But i want to use those files for a particular component.Not for all

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2: import external js file into component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37081943/angular2-import-external-js-file-into-component)

Comment: As I have many components in my angular app

Comment: I have already seen that that solution codeherk .It didn't understand

Comment: @codeherk In that question he wanted to add functions of a js Files for using it in angular component.But i only want to include js file same as we import  Html and css in a component

Answer (score 1):

Scripts and styles should be imported into your `angular.json` file:-

look for the following line and import your css and js into those:-

```
"styles": [
    "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
    "./node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
    "./node_modules/semantic-ui/dist/semantic.min.css",
    "src/styles.scss"
],
"scripts": []
```

Comment: but i want to use it only for a particular component

Answer (score 0):

Are those script tags belong only to that component? If no, what about placing these tags in the `index.html` file?

Answer (score 0):

Let me take Jquery for example, Assume Jquery path included in the index.html file like you did above, then in the component where I want to use Jquery, add below priece of code above the @Component decorator, then you can use the Jquery functionality inside that component only.

```
declare var $;
```

Example component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

//declare dollor($) here
declare var $;
@Component({ templateUrl: 'home.component.html' })
export class HomeComponent {
    public divElement: any;
    constructor( ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
     this.divElement = $('div');
    }
}
```