# Imported function from js file, doesn't run in TS file

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli

I'm trying to call a JS function inside a component in my TS file, but I'm getting an exception.

Component

```js
import '../../../assets/js/gantt/ganttMaster.js';
export class TaskComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    var r = new GanttMaster();
  }
}
```

Error:

```
Error referecences error: GanttMaster is not defined
```

Comment: Where is it defined...?

Comment: I imported already:  import '../../../assets/js/gantt/ganttMaster.js';

Comment: the import syntax seems to be incorrect. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JvaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the way you import the `.js` file:

```
import * as gantt from '../../../assets/js/gantt/ganttMaster.js';
export class TaskComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    var r = new gantt.GanttMaster();
  }
}
```

If you want to use `GanttMaster` among several components, you can import the `.js` file in `angular.json` and declare a constant in `app.module.ts` like `declare const GanttMaster: any`. Then you can use it in your application.

Hope this helps.

---

**UPDATE**

Alternatively, you can import it the way you've already done, but declare the function manually before the import:

```
declare const GanttMaster: any;
import from '../../../assets/js/gantt/ganttMaster.js';
export class TaskComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    var r = new GanttMaster();
  }
}
```

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37084553/1331040

Comment: actually, I try alreay but it not working, through error on webpackage like this: "TaskComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1 ERROR TypeError: _assets_js_gantt_ganttMaster_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_18__.GanttMaster is not a constructor"

Comment: Updated the answer. Can you try this one?

Comment: I'm try for your Update already, but it still got "ERROR ReferenceError: GanttMaster is not defined"

Answer (score 0):

In my project i load a js file from assets, something like this:

add this JavaScript file in scripts array in angular.json file like as above you have added jquery library.

```
"scripts": [
  .....
  "src/assets/js/custom.js"
]
```

custom.js:

```
function myTest() {
    alert('Welcome to custom js');
}
```

You need declare in your component

```
declare const myTest: any;
```

Comment: I try it already, it same error above  "ERROR ReferenceError: GanttMaster is not defined"