# Import js in angular component

Tags: angular

I developped an Angular 12 app, and i'm trying to import the .js file in my components.
I tried to import it like  this

```
import * as script from 'src/assets/js/home/home.js';
```

but the .js files are not found, i tried with .ts and there is no problem.
Why does the .js files can't be imported like this and how can I import it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 2: import external js file into component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37081943/angular-2-import-external-js-file-into-component)

Comment: try `import from 'src/assets/js/home/home.js';`. You could also include it in the `angular.json` file in the `scripts` section.

Comment: @Rukshan No because in this case the path found the file and in mine it not.

Answer (score 1):

The base path in angular.json is set to the src directly.

Hence you can directly call this

```
import * as script from 'assets/js/home/home.js';
```