# How to inject and import dependencies at run time in angular 2

Tags: dependency-injection, typescript, angular

I started learning angularJS2 for my Social project. It is huge project and the app requires different activities at different stages and also a one page app. I doesn't want to load all dependencies at first time. My first screen will be login/signup after going threw these there will be screens according user's personalization which requires different dependencies. So basically how to achieve this, is my question.

Comment: [possibly of interest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34489916/load-external-js-script-dynamically-in-angular-2/34489991)

Comment: yes it is of my interest but i doesn't know how that can solve my problem I will read that twice thrice ...thanks

Comment: np - but frankly, I doubt it's going to be very helpful for what you're doing. As I said, I just thought it might be of interest... @GünterZöchbauer is correct that framework support for this will be landing in a future RC, and you're almost-certainly going to want to abandon whatever you do now in favor of using that once it's there, so don't waste too much time.

Answer (score 3):

> So basically how to achieve this

You are looking for *lazy loading*.

This is a topic covered well here : http://blog.mgechev.com/2015/09/30/lazy-loading-components-routes-services-router-angular-2/

Comment: according to this link we can add dependencies ilike this `providers: [NameList],` right or wrong :)

Answer (score 2):

Angular is working on a build tool that results in the app only loading the components that are required for a specific route. You won't have to do anything to get this feature except using the router.

Comment: I don't know. It was mentioned in a talk at ng-conf. They built a new router from scratch very recently because the "old" one introduced some limitations for lazy loading. I guess it will still take a few months until it will be available and stable.

Comment: ok will that be supporting multiple views or again we have to use third party like angular-ui router

Comment: What do you mean by "multiple views"? I guess multiple `<router-outlet>`s. This also was limited in the "old" router and now allows multiple `<router-outlet>`s at every level.

Comment: multiple view means state based loading like...
if i loaded a page say index now i want a view inside that index page which can load either login screen or signup screen but not together instead based on rout like `index/login` and `index/signup` and when user directly access any of them the index page should be loaded automatically and then login or signup screen inside that

Comment: I see. I don't know. I guess we have to wait until it becomes available.