# Execute javascript injected into Angular 2 templates

Tags: angular, xss

I have a CMS that stores some HTML contents. In my Angular web app I am getting these contents and injecting them into my templates.

Let's say "myContent" content get from the model is:

```
<div>Test</div>
<script type="text/javascript">alert("test")</script>
```

In the component that use this content I have done:

```
export class PlaceholderComponent implements OnInit  {
  @Input() placeholderKey : string;

  private placeHolderContent : SafeHtml;

  constructor(private modelProvider: ModelProviderService, private sanitizer: DomSanitizer){}

  ngOnInit() {
    if(this.model.placeholders) {
      this.placeHolderContent = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.model.placeholders[this.placeholderKey]);
    }
  }
}
```

And in the template of this component

```
<div [innerHtml]="placeHolderContent"></div>
```

As a result, the html is correctly injected in the template, including the script tag, but the alert is never executed (note that console.log("test") is not working either).

Do you have a solution to inject HTML with JavaScript that would be run when the component finish loading?

(Note: if I use jquery inside my Angular component to insert HTML in the template it works!)

Comment: Seems similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38163531/how-to-load-script-file-from-component-html).

Comment: Using `innerHtml` is not a good practice use `<ng-content></ng-content>` instead.

Comment: @PankajParkar it does not seems so, I do not wan tot execute the script form my component.

Comment: @MaximeGélinas could you please provide more details? Here I do not want to have a standard layout into which I inject different templates. I though this was the use of ng-content.

Comment: @jthe even I was trying to load script from template, that I saw similar with me.

Comment: It isn't possible for security reasons, `<script>` nodes should be re-inserted into DOM (for instance, with jQuery) manually. If the purpose is sharing *data* and not behaviour (`alert`), your best bet is to embed JSON into html and then parse it.

Comment: Why do you have to run script outside of the Angular scope?

Comment: @MaximeGélinas, our customer can insert html dynamically with the CMS that can interact with other vendors (called through javascript).

Comment: @jthe Its just a supposition but maybe if you inject the HTML after the view's initialisation (after the security check that remove the script tags)?

Comment: @MaximeGélinas thanks I will try that next time I can work on this.