# How to reload the current Angular 2 Component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-components

How can I reload the same component again in Angular 2?

Here is my code below:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef, Renderer } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { productModel } from '../_models/index';
import { categoryListService } from '../_services/index';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product',
  templateUrl: 'product.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['product.component.css']
})
export class productComponent implements OnInit {
  uidproduct: productModel;
  param: number;
  constructor(
    private elementRef: ElementRef,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private categoryListService: categoryListService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(product => {
      console.log('logging sub product obj', product);
    });
    this.uidproduct = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('product'));
    var s = document.createElement("script");
    s.type = "text/javascript";
    s.src = "http://this/external/script/needs/to/be/loaded/each/time.js";
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.appendChild(s);
  }
  nextproduct(){ 
    let i = this.uidproduct.order;
    this.categoryListService.findNextproduct(this.uidproduct);
    this.param = ++i;
    this.router.navigate([`/product/${this.param}`]);
  }
}
```

`nextproduct()` is bound to a click event in the template.

The `uidproduct` is a JSON object that has a number of properties and i'm updating the DOM with `{{uidproduct.classname}}`

I'm using this in the template like this:

```
<div id="selected-product" class="{{uidproduct.classname}}">
```

When I click the `<button (click)="nextproduct()">` it will change the class property in the DOM but I need to reload the component for the external script to have effect.

Comment: I don't think so component reloading option would be good ever, what do you mean by *I need to reolad the component for the external script to have effect.*?

Comment: The external script is targeting that particular DOM element class property and rendering a particular product to the DOM. Cheers!

Comment: What external script?

Comment: @Dave you can't load external script from template(it would be security threat), I'd recommend you to go through [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38163531/2435473)

Comment: @PankajParkar it works for when ngOnint is triggered, Do you have any suggestions on how to reload the component? thanks

Comment: @PankajParkar I have now removed the external script from the template but any updates on how to reload the component would be awesome!

Answer (score 22):

You can use `*ngIf` to re-render the content of a template:

```ts
@Component({
  selector: '...',
  template: `
<ng-container *ngIf="!rerender">
 template content here
</ng-container>`
})
export class MyComponent {
  rerender = false;
  constructor(private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef){}
  doRerender() {
    this.rerender = true;
    this.cdRef.detectChanges();
    this.rerender = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Great tricks, Like this, i search so many thing and tried many legal step but could not successes. In my language good 'JUGAD'

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why you need to reload the component. If you're binding to the various fields of `uidproduct`, then reloading that should refresh the values shown in the component. So reloading the component does nothing but add overhead.

If there is a terrific reason not mentioned here why you think you still need to do this, then here is what you do:

1. Navigate to another (possibly blank) component.
2. Navigate directly back.

The problem is that you need to wait for the first navigation to finish before doing the second one.

In your component, import NavigationEnd:

```
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
```

And then subscribe to it in your constructor:

```
constructor(private thingService: ThisThingService, private router: Router) { 
   router.events.subscribe(event => {
    if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
      if (event.url === '/blank') {
        this.router.navigate(['product']); 
      }
    }
  });
```

Notice that I wait for `NavigationEnd` to happen and then check to see I was routing to my blank component. If it is the blank component's path, I navigate back to the product. If you really need to pass that ID, just store it on your object and add it here.

Instead of routing to your product page in `nextproduct()`, navigate to `blank`.

```
this.router.navigate(['blank']);
```

And that should reload your component perfectly fine.

The problem I intentionally left in for simplicity, is that the `subscribe` call in the constructor will execute for every reload. So as an exercise to the reader, take it out of the constructor and create a nice service for it, or move it to the constructor of your app component, or maybe to your routing module or wherever makes sense to you.

Comment: Thanks it's working, though logic is not straight. @Günter Zöchbauer answer doesn't renew my services, but it gives all data renew in my component :)