# cant add script file to components html

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template

I have had a script file reference in index.html(root);
index.html:

```
    <script src="page1.js"></script>
<script src="assets/sliderfunctions.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/custom.js"></script>
```

no need  sliderfunctions.js here, it contains some specific functions about slider so I carry it to slider.component.html file but as you guess it doesnt work as I expected actually it never loaded to browser..

slider.component.ts:

```
import {Component,ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector:'app-slider',
    templateUrl:'../templates/slider.component.html'
})
export class SliderComponent{
    constructor(){}
}
```

slider.component.html:

```
 <script src="page1.js"></script>
<script src="assets/sliderfunctions.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/custom.js"></script>
```

(I carried 3 of them because order of scripts is important)so I want to get a specific point that I already make search on net but cant figure out how to add script file within component templates

Comment: How are you using them inside the component exactly?

Comment: please take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38163531/2435473)... Technically this option considered as security issue...

Comment: @PankajParkar yeah it shows the way but how to load this script file to browser inside the component function? do you think is fine simple http request ? or ?

Comment: @PankajParkar can you post your example as answer here

Comment: @TyForHelpDude basically what you could do is, Instead of specifying script file inside a html.. do call `require('filePath')` inside `component.ts`

Comment: @PankajParkar you are lifesaver, let me accept your answer please eloborate it to make it clear for others who seeks same solution. thank you

Comment: @TyForHelpDude I've added answer below.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way you're thinking of is considered as security threat. You could either follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38163531/how-to-load-script-file-from-component-html)

**OR**

You can refer script file from the `component.ts` file, just by doing `System.import`/`require`

```
System.import('filepath.js'); //or below one
require('filepath.js');
```

Comment: how do I load it after other js files?