# How to load a script for a specific route in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular

I have to load a script that calculates the analytics on a specific route in angular 4. But for other routes the script should not get loaded.

I tried adding the script in index.html but the script will be loaded for all the routes. Any workaround for this?

below is the script

```js
(function(a,b,c,d,e,f){
    a.hj=a.hj||function(){(a.hj.q=a.hj.q||[]).push(arguments)};
    a._hjSettings={hjid:xx,hjsv:xxx};
    e=b.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    f=b.createElement('script');f.async=1;
    f.src=t+a._hjSettings.hjid+d+a._hjSettings.hjsv;
    e.appendChild(f);
})(window,document,'https://xx.xx.com/c/xx-','.js?sv=');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add it in `index.html` then the script will be loaded in `all components`, and this is not your need. So you can try loading the script from the `ts file` of the component in which you want to load the script. So in the `ts file`, you can do it as follow.

```
System.import('https://xx.xx.com/c/xx-','.js?sv='); //or below one
require('https://xx.xx.com/c/xx-','.js?sv=');
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41402204/10971575