# javascript function are not working with angular 5 correctly

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a problem like this. I am making an angular application. In there, I have made an animated Login. This is my component HTML file.

```
<div class="panda" xmlns="">
  <div class="ear"></div>
  <div class="face">
    <div class="eye-shade"></div>
    <div class="eye-white">
      <div class="eye-ball"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="eye-shade rgt"></div>
    <div class="eye-white rgt">
      <div class="eye-ball"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="nose"></div>
    <div class="mouth"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="body"> </div>
  <div class="foot">
    <div class="finger"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="foot rgt">
    <div class="finger"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<form>
  <div class="hand"></div>
  <div class="hand rgt"></div>
  <h1>Panda Login</h1>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input required="required" class="form-control"/>
    <label class="form-label">Username    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input id="password" type="password" required="required" class="form-control"/>
    <label class="form-label">Password</label>
    <p class="alert">Invalid Credentials..!!</p>
    <button class="btn">Login </button>
  </div>
</form>
<script>
  $('#password').focusin(function(){
    $('form').addClass('up')
  });
  $('#password').focusout(function(){
    $('form').removeClass('up')
  });

  // Panda Eye move
  $(document).on( "mousemove", function( event ) {
    var dw = $(document).width() / 15;
    var dh = $(document).height() / 15;
    var x = event.pageX/ dw;
    var y = event.pageY/ dh;
    $('.eye-ball').css({
      width : x,
      height : y
    });
  });

  // validation


  $('.btn').click(function(){
    $('form').addClass('wrong-entry');
    setTimeout(function(){
      $('form').removeClass('wrong-entry');
    },3000 );
  });

</script>
```

This is my component CSS file.

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dancing+Script|Roboto);
*, *:after, *:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #cc3367;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.panda {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

.face {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin: 50px auto;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  z-index: 50;
  position: relative;
}

.ear, .ear:after {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #000;
  z-index: 5;
  border: 10px solid #fff;
  left: -15px;
  top: -15px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
.ear:after {
  content: '';
  left: 125px;
}

.eye-shade {
  background: #000;
  width: 50px;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 35px;
  left: 25px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(220deg);
  transform: rotate(220deg);
  border-radius: 25px/20px 30px 35px 40px;
}
.eye-shade.rgt {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(140deg);
  transform: rotate(140deg);
  left: 105px;
}

.eye-white {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 500;
  left: 40px;
  top: 80px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.eye-white.rgt {
  right: 40px;
  left: auto;
}

.eye-ball {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  max-width: 10px;
  max-height: 10px;
  transition: 0.1s;
}
.eye-ball:after {
  content: '';
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 100%;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

.nose {
  position: absolute;
  height: 20px;
  width: 35px;
  bottom: 40px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 50px 20px/30px 15px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(15deg);
  transform: rotate(15deg);
  background: #000;
}

.body {
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  left: -20px;
  border-radius: 100px 100px 100px 100px/126px 126px 96px 96px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 282px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.hand, .hand:after, .hand:before {
  width: 40px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  background: #000;
  margin: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 70px;
  left: -25px;
}
.hand:after, .hand:before {
  content: '';
  left: -5px;
  top: 11px;
}
.hand:before {
  top: 26px;
}
.hand.rgt, .rgt.hand:after, .rgt.hand:before {
  left: auto;
  right: -25px;
}
.hand.rgt:after, .hand.rgt:before {
  left: auto;
  right: -5px;
}

.foot {
  top: 360px;
  left: -80px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #000;
  z-index: 1400;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 40px 40px 39px 40px/26px 26px 63px 63px;
  width: 82px;
  height: 120px;
}
.foot:after {
  content: '';
  width: 55px;
  height: 65px;
  background: #222;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
.foot .finger, .foot .finger:after, .foot .finger:before {
  position: absolute;
  width: 25px;
  height: 35px;
  background: #222;
  border-radius: 100%;
  top: 10px;
  right: 5px;
}
.foot .finger:after, .foot .finger:before {
  content: '';
  right: 30px;
  width: 20px;
  top: 0;
}
.foot .finger:before {
  right: 55px;
  top: 5px;
}
.foot.rgt {
  left: auto;
  right: -80px;
}
.foot.rgt .finger, .foot.rgt .finger:after, .foot.rgt .finger:before {
  left: 5px;
  right: auto;
}
.foot.rgt .finger:after {
  left: 30px;
  right: auto;
}
.foot.rgt .finger:before {
  left: 55px;
  right: auto;
}

form {
  display: none;
  max-width: 400px;
  padding: 20px 40px;
  background: #fff;
  height: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  transition: 0.3s;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-100px);
  transform: translateY(-100px);
  z-index: 500;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
}
form.up {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-180px);
  transform: translateY(-180px);
}

h1 {
  color: #FF4081;
  font-family: 'Dancing Script', cursive;
}

.btn {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 35px;
  border: 1px solid #FF4081;
  margin-top: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
  box-shadow: 0 50px #FF4081 inset;
  color: #fff;
}
.btn:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 #FF4081 inset;
  color: #FF4081;
}
.btn:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.form-group {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #666;
}
.form-group + .form-group {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.form-group .form-label {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 5px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.form-group .form-control {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
  height: 35px;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  padding: 5px 0;
  transition: 0.3s;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #777;
  color: #555;
}
.form-group .form-control:invalid {
  outline: none;
}
.form-group .form-control:focus, .form-group .form-control:valid {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 1px #FF4081;
  border-color: #FF4081;
}
.form-group .form-control:focus + .form-label, .form-group .form-control:valid + .form-label {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #FF4081;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-15px);
  transform: translateY(-15px);
}

.alert {
  position: absolute;
  color: #f00;
  font-size: 16px;
  right: -180px;
  top: -300px;
  z-index: 200;
  padding: 30px 25px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0, 0);
  transform: scale(0, 0);
  -moz-transition: linear 0.4s 0.6s;
  -o-transition: linear 0.4s 0.6s;
  -webkit-transition: linear 0.4s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.6s;
  transition: linear 0.4s 0.6s;
}
.alert:after, .alert:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #fff;
  left: -19px;
  bottom: -8px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.alert:before {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  left: -35px;
  bottom: -25px;
}

.wrong-entry {
  -webkit-animation: wrong-log 0.3s;
  animation: wrong-log 0.3s;
}
.wrong-entry .alert {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
  transform: scale(1, 1);
}
@-webkit-keyframes eye-blink {
  to {
    height: 30px;
  }
}
@keyframes eye-blink {
  to {
    height: 30px;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes wrong-log {
  0%, 100% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  20% , 60% {
    left: 20px;
  }
  40% , 80% {
    left: -20px;
  }
}
@keyframes wrong-log {
  0%, 100% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  20% , 60% {
    left: 20px;
  }
  40% , 80% {
    left: -20px;
  }
}
```

This is my module.ts file.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {ROUTING} from './app.routing';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar/navbar.component';
import { SetColorDirective } from './directives/set-color.directive';
import { AdminLoginComponent } from './admin/admin-login/admin-login.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    SetColorDirective,
    AdminLoginComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ROUTING
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And Here I am providing my angular-cli.json file.

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "frontend"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
        "styles.css"

      ],
      "scripts": [

        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
      ],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "component": {}
  }
}
```

My view file is giving the right output when I hit ng serve. But animation is not working without giving any error. I have tried so many examples and the given suggestion even in the stack overflow examples. But those examples were unable to full fill my requirements. Can someone help me to solve this problem?

Thank You!!

Comment: You shouldn't be mixing jQuery and messing around with the DOM like this and Angular. The problem itself might be that view encapsulation mangles the class names and thus the embedded Javascript in the template no longer works correctly.

Comment: How can I solve that? Can You guide me to do it correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**First**: They are not javascript functions. You have used jQuery functions.

**Second**: Scripts are not allowed in component's HTML. You can use script tags only in index.html. See [this](https://angular.io/guide/security#xss). You can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38163531/9766215) instead.

Comment: With your help, I changed my component.ts file to use jquery functions. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks , i realized that angular removes <script> tags for security reasons.