# Angular draging not working inside wpf app

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, cefsharp

I have windows 10, 64 bit and I was trying to run angular app inside my wpf application.
Page seams to render fine ,but when i try to use basic dragging (and draging related functions) it's only works when i put all the scripts inside index.html. When I run my app it's always working  for chrome and other browsers ,but in cefsharp there is problem when web application is splited in many files.

I build my angular app with command *ng build*  and copy output files to the folder ".\Assets\HTML\GPS".
CefSharp is running in the code below:

```
public UcGpsWeb()
        {
            CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
            settings.CefCommandLineArgs["disable-features"] = "BlockInsecurePrivateNetworkRequests";
            settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-web-security", "disable-web-security");
            settings.RegisterScheme(new CefCustomScheme
            {
                SchemeName = "localfolder",
                DomainName = "cefsharp",
                SchemeHandlerFactory = new FolderSchemeHandlerFactory(
                    rootFolder: @".\Assets\HTML\GPS\",
                    hostName: "cefsharp",
                    defaultPage: "index.html" // will default to index.html
                )
            });
            CefSharp.Cef.Initialize(settings);
            InitializeComponent();
            Loaded += (s, e) =>
            {
                //WebBrowser.ShowDevTools();
                WebBrowser.Address = "localfolder://cefsharp/";
            };
        }
```

When I use  *ng serve* application works fine in both scenarios in the chrome and other browsers, but when I deploy my application it entirely works only when all code is put inside index.html

I have created 2 simple projects that have exacly the same code with only difference between them being the localization of html code and only one of them is working.
[Working](https://github.com/Sznopik/AngularComponent)
[Not working](https://github.com/Sznopik/AngularComponent/tree/NotWorking)
Draging functions are very important to my aplication. Honestly have spend on this whole week and I still dont know if the problem is inside wpf app, or should I use some different approach to produce working web app files from Angular.

Every othe script or function that I use works in both cases ,but for example dragstart only works if scripts are located in index.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javascript function are not working with angular 5 correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50894744/javascript-function-are-not-working-with-angular-5-correctly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have found the problem. The Cefsharp have drag functions is disabled by defalut. While functions called for example by dragstart  still starts ,it wont use dragevent.
To fix i added

```
AllowDrop= true;
```

to the "Loaded" scope in Cefsharp