# Lazy Loading a Library/Dependency with Angular 2 / Webpack without Router

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, mapbox, mapbox-gl

I have a [Mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com) web map in my Angular 2 application.

The map attaches itself to a `<div>` tag, like so:

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

I have two different libraries I can use for my web map: [Mapbox GL JS](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/), which uses WebGL, or [Mapbox.js](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v3.0.1/), which does not use WebGL and is more compatible with older computers and browsers.

When the user loads my application, I want to test to see if their browser can use the WebGL library. ([Example here from Mapbox documentation.](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/check-for-support/))

If they support it, I want to load the Mapbox GL JS library.

If they do not support it, I want to load Mapbox.js instead as a fallback.

([Vanilla Javascript example of this behavior here.](https://bl.ocks.org/danswick/c280d49d7dae91dc351a8f0d4da99af0))

I want to do this **without loading both libraries.** I only want to load one library or the other, and all of the associated code that I have written. (Each library has its own different syntax/formatting, so I cannot reuse the same associated code for either library.)

What do you think is the best strategy for doing this in an Angular 2 application using the Webpack module bundler?

**NOTE:** In this instance, I cannot use the router to separate the two different maps; otherwise this could be a lot easier....

Comment: Without routing, can't you just use `System.import`?

Comment: @ Harangue - I think your'e right. also, [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34489916/load-external-js-script-dynamically-in-angular-2) already answered this question... at least in my opinion

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you both very much.

Answer (score 0):

A good solution (for Webpack) is to use either `System.import` or `require.ensure`, as explained in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34489991/3403895

`System.import` method:

```
export class MyAppComponent {
  constructor(){
    System.import('path/to/your/module').then(refToLoadedModule => {
      refToLoadedModule.someFunction();
    }
  );
}
```

`require.ensure` method:

```
export class MyAppComponent {
  constructor() {
     require.ensure(['path/to/your/module'], require => {
        let yourModule = require('path/to/your/module');
        yourModule.someFunction();
     }); 
  }
}
```

This link also seems to be a good tutorial for this: [Code Splitting in Angular 2 with Webpack 2 (http://blog.waffle.io/code-splitting-angular-2-webpack-2/)](http://blog.waffle.io/code-splitting-angular-2-webpack-2/)

Many thanks to Harangue and ymz