# Angular 2 - Bootstrap and AdminLTE Assets Collision

Tags: javascript, angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, adminlte

I have an e-commercial web site. I developed it using Sails.js, Bootstrap, PostgreSQL... And I used AdminLTE as admin panel.

Now I would like to refactor front-end with Angular 2. But there is problem about Bootstrap. When i include scripts(Bootstrap, AdminLTE) and styles(Bootstrap, AdminLTE) in index.html. AdminLTE makes appearance different.

How can i include scripts and styles for component?

For example;
if Admin component comes up then script1, script2 and style1, style2 will be included.
if home component comes up then home_script and home_style will be included.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Angular documentation - https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html

Comment: What about scripts?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34489916/load-external-js-script-dynamically-in-angular-2