# How to use external javascript api in .Net core MVC + angular?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-mvc

I would like to create a map display application using javascript API like below with .Net Core MVC + angular, how can I do it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
<head>
    <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />
    <title>TEST</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #sample_map {
            width: 660px;
            height: 280px;
        }
    </style>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://xxxxx/js/map/xxjsapi'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        window.onload = function() {
            Xxapi.mapHost = 'api-map-pre.com';
            Xxapi.auth('xxxxxxxxxx', task_func);
        }
        function task_func(authStatus) {
            if (authStatus != 'success') {
                return;
            }
            var options = {
                centerPosition: new Xxapi.Util.LonLat(139.70030321482975, 35.68955994193983),
                mapScale: 16
            };
            Xxapi.mapCreate('sample_map', options);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='sample_map'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is a external javascript API and no source and no configfiles.
And it seems to be using callback.
I looking at: [Load external js script dynamically in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34489916/load-external-js-script-dynamically-in-angular-2) and tried, but isn't work.
Plaese help me.