# How can I integrate scripts to Angular 4 component?

Tags: angular, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, angular2-template

I am following documentation on Google Map Api services (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering) .I want to use show map clusters in the app component but Angular component does not support importing external scripts. Even if I import scripts I am unable to change the content of the scripts (for example change var locations..) . So how can I import and maintain those scripts in component.ts file. When copy pasting the scripts directly to component.ts the errors occur such as variables are not declared since they are declared in external script file. Please do not recommend me agm angular maps since it does not support map clusters. Please help me to solve this problem.

```
<script>

      function initMap() {

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 3,
          center: {lat: -28.024, lng: 140.887}
        });

        // Create an array of alphabetical characters used to label the markers.
        var labels = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

        // Add some markers to the map.
        // Note: The code uses the JavaScript Array.prototype.map() method to
        // create an array of markers based on a given "locations" array.
        // The map() method here has nothing to do with the Google Maps API.
        var markers = locations.map(function(location, i) {
          return new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location,
            label: labels[i % labels.length]
          });
        });

        // Add a marker clusterer to manage the markers.
        var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers,
            {imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'});
      }
      var locations = [
        {lat: -31.563910, lng: 147.154312},
        {lat: -33.718234, lng: 150.363181},
        {lat: -33.727111, lng: 150.371124},
        {lat: -33.848588, lng: 151.209834},
        {lat: -33.851702, lng: 151.216968},
        {lat: -34.671264, lng: 150.863657},
        {lat: -35.304724, lng: 148.662905},
        {lat: -36.817685, lng: 175.699196},
        {lat: -36.828611, lng: 175.790222},
        {lat: -37.750000, lng: 145.116667},
        {lat: -37.759859, lng: 145.128708},
        {lat: -37.765015, lng: 145.133858},
        {lat: -37.770104, lng: 145.143299},
        {lat: -37.773700, lng: 145.145187},
        {lat: -37.774785, lng: 145.137978},
        {lat: -37.819616, lng: 144.968119},
        {lat: -38.330766, lng: 144.695692},
        {lat: -39.927193, lng: 175.053218},
        {lat: -41.330162, lng: 174.865694},
        {lat: -42.734358, lng: 147.439506},
        {lat: -42.734358, lng: 147.501315},
        {lat: -42.735258, lng: 147.438000},
        {lat: -43.999792, lng: 170.463352}
      ]
    </script>
    <script src="https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/markerclusterer.js">
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
```

Comment: @Arg0n  . Hi Arg0n. No unfortunately Angular does not support it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this by following tutorial .The problem was that we should declare variables in order to use external script. https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2016/01/include-external-javascript-libraries-in-an-angular-2-typescript-project/
Or we can also use typings to install typescript definition files which can be taken from https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types

Answer (score 0):

angular supports importing external scripts .have a look at this thread.
[Load external js script dynamically in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34489916/load-external-js-script-dynamically-in-angular-2)

Comment: Yes ,finally i found it.I followed nice tutorial from Nic Raboy and it worked.Thank you for help!

Comment: post your reference. Thanks