# How to load External Javascript Libraries into Angular 4 components

Tags: javascript, angular, square-connect

I have a problem where I need to use a specific 3rd party library to generate a nonce to use the square connect api. I am having troubles finding how to load the external javascript library since they don't have a node_module that I can load like I usually do. By external library I mean something like this `<script src="https://js.squareup.com/v2/paymentform " type="text/javascript">` I have not found a good way to to load this into my application so that I can use it. Any ideas on how I can solve this problem?

Comment: If you use angular-cli you should put it in the script section in .angular-cli.json

Comment: Use this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34489916/how-to-load-external-scripts-dynamically-in-angular/42766146#42766146

Answer (score 1):

A few options that I have used:

1. Global script using [angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-scripts)

   ```
   "scripts": [
      "global-script.js",
      { "input": "lazy-script.js", "lazy": true },
      { "input": "pre-rename-script.js", "output": "renamed-script" },
   ]
   ```
2. Require in a specific module

   ```
   import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
   ...
   require('chart.js');
   require('../../libs/chartjs-plugin-annotation');
   ...
   ```
3. Add a global script at runtime based on some condition

   ```
   if (this.usesCKEditor(permissions) && !window['CKEDITOR']) {
       const url = '//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.7.3/full/ckeditor.js';
       const script = document.createElement('script');
       script.type = 'text/javascript';
       script.src = url;
       document.body.appendChild(script);
   }
   // must check if the script has loaded before using it
   ```

Comment: On option number one do you have to download the script first or can I put the link url?

Comment: @JonathanJensen  just an FYI, you aren't allowed (by Square) to download the script and include it, so options like number 3 are going to be better for you.

Comment: @JonathanJensen you can put the url in option 1 also

Comment: @tristansokol Thanks for the update. I am aware of them not allowing the downloading of their scripts which is why I asked the question. But if I did not know about it then that would have been helpful. So thank you.

Comment: @SumamaWaheed When I try option number one I get this error:
ERROR in multi script-loader!./src/https:/js.squareup.com/v2/paymentform
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/Users/jpjensen/Projects/build-a-bracelet/front-end/src/https:/js.squareup.com/v2/paymentform' in '/Users/jpjensen/Projects/build-a-bracelet/front-end/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/webpack-configs'
 @ multi script-loader!./src/https:/js.squareup.com/v2/paymentform

code https://gist.github.com/jonje/703071339542964bed461742f10c5c90

Comment: @Sumama Waheed Where can I put this piece of code (option 3)?

Comment: @Ruthi constructor or ngOnInit(). You can use the onload callback to know the when script has loaded

Answer (score 1):

**First Approach:**

Refer the scripts inside the `angular-cli.json` file.

```
"scripts": [
    "../path" 
 ];
```

**Second Approach**

You can create your own directive to load script as below

```
import { Directive, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[appLoadScript]'
})
export class LoadScriptDirective implements OnInit{

    @Input('script') param:  any;

    ngOnInit() {
        let node = document.createElement('script');
        node.src = this.param;
        node.type = 'text/javascript';
        node.async = false;
        node.charset = 'utf-8';
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(node);
    }

}
```

> HOW TO USE

```
<i appLoadScript  [script]="'https://js.squareup.com/v2/paymentform'"></i>
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-dn53ub?file=app/app.component.html)**

Comment: Second approach works well, but I prefer the first one. Is there a way to make use of environment variables with the first approach? I need to inject in an API key.