# angular2 dynamic html content loading with script tag and styles

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

We are getting HTML content from the database by using API call. We are using third party script url.

Example:
`<div style="height:500px"><script type='text/javascript' src='//www.google.com'></script></div>`

We need to display above HTML content into existing angular2 application.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `innerHTML` to load dynamic HTML content onto any elements like this -

```
yourData = <div style="height:500px"><script type='text/javascript' src='//www.google.com'></script></div>

<div [innerHTML]='yourData'></div>
```

[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qvnvzs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

this may help you to load dynamic script

- [How to load external scripts dynamically in Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34489916/how-to-load-external-scripts-dynamically-in-angular)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. the above-mentioned solution is not working in an angular2 application with script tags. Only it is displaying DIV tag not loading the script

Comment: yes , `innerHTML` will load only HTML content into your DOM with style if any

Comment: okay, then how can I run a script using a script tag. The script loads a wizard with menu items list

Comment: @user3149922 check my updated answer with helpful link