# Angular - Loading external script through CDN on internal navigation

Tags: javascript, html, angular, cdn, masonry

I'm trying to create a masonry layout by loading in `<script src="https://unpkg.com/masonry-layout@4/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>`
at the top of the index page and using it on a component in my web-app.
This problem probably isn't masonry-specific, the general problem is an included script in the header not loading on internal navigation.

I've chosen to initialize the masonry in the HTML. The problem occurs when using internal navigation to get to the page. If I reload the page to the correct URL the script does its thing and creates the desired layout. However, when navigating through routerlinks the scripts doesn't load, or something else is wrong making it not apply.

Here's a picture of the correct loading which occurs when refreshing the page:
[image]

And one of the incorrect loading when navigating internally to the page:
[image]

The HTML for the page:

```
<div class="grid" data-masonry='{ "itemSelector": ".grid-item", "columnWidth": 5 }'>
  <div *ngFor="let card_text of card_array" class="grid-item">
    <div class="cardTop">
      <img src="/static/images/ordercards/greenOrderIcon.svg">
      <div class="orderId">
        Order # Some number
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cardMain">
      {{ card_text }}
    </div>
    <div class="cardBot">
      <a routerLink="/orders"> Learn More ></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and in the index.html the script mentioned at the top is included.

Any ideas on how to load the script each time the page is internally navigated to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible your angular script is running before the mansory js is loaded.
Try loading the library with load-script or load-js scripts which will give you a promise of when it's finished loading, then you execute your mansory layout constructor.

Comment: Solved it by loading it dynamically with the component [with the help of this previous SO solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34489916/how-to-load-external-scripts-dynamically-in-angular) as you specified!

Answer (score 1):

If during the internal navigation, you are calling any component and you have wrote any logic there, then you need to import that script to that component also.

I have used many external scripts and my project is working fine.

Below is the line of code for example that probably you might need to import the scripts.

```
import * as utility from 'assets/js/core/utility.js';
```

This will load the script in the component as well.

Comment: Just a quick clarification on that, I download the file instead of using it through a <script>-tag on the index page, and in the component I import it from the file location? 

Just making sure since I'm not calling the script anywhere inside the component.

Answer (score 0):

I would specifically suggest that you load the masonry layout script when all other page item has loaded. This means you should add it to the bottom of your index page.