# Dynamically load Google Tag Manager and switch in SPA

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, single-page-application, google-tag-manager

The marketing department wants to separate the Google Tag Manager per country. For an normal website, not SPA, we can easily do this based on the URL. Would the client switch to another URL, then the page would be refreshed, country code added in the URL and the correct GTM can be loaded.

Now for a SPA (in Angular,Typescript) this is a little bit harder. Currently we don't have a language/country parameter in this application, but it can be changed anyways throughout the web application. Of course the page would not be refreshed.

I am trying to find a way to dynamically load and unload GTM script.

I can successfully load and unload an `<script>` element in the `<head>` but the tag manager adds more elements.

```
public loadScriptSimple(country : string) {
    //first remove existing node
    var existing = document.getElementById("tagmanager");
    if (existing && existing.parentNode) {
        existing.parentNode.removeChild(existing);
    }
    //
    console.log('adding node to head...');
    let node = document.createElement('script');
    if (country === "NL") {
        node.textContent =
            "(function (w, d, s, l, i) {w[l] = w[l] ....(window, document, 'script', 'dataLayer', 'GTM-XXX');";
    } else {//todo for later loading others
        node.textContent =
            "(function (w, d, s, l, i) {w[l] = w[l] ....(window, document, 'script', 'dataLayer', 'GTM-YYY');";
    }

    node.type = 'text/javascript';
    node.async = true;
    node.charset = 'utf-8';
    node.setAttribute("id", "tagmanager");
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(node);
    console.log('loaded script');
}
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38473334/2901207

So it would be possible to load it on the first request (e.g. the first time the country is decided based on IP) but after changing the country, two tags would be loaded.

Is there any simple way to remove the existing elements and then create the new ones like above?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to handling the removal of the additional elements added by tag manager?

Comment: Nope, I called-the-day on this and told marketing department that it's not possible, only way this would be possible is to load scripts that are country-specific manually. Only then it is possible to delete node's per name or id.