# How to include the External script only to the component?

Tags: angular, typescript

I angular app I have `form` component which is dependent on an external script to work properly,

I know that to include the external script in the angular we can do one of the following:-

1. make an entry in `angular.json` file
2. include the script in `index.html`
3. include the script file in `component.html` file
4. import the script in `component.ts` file

All the above method include script globally, and it does not work when the component is not loaded.

I want script attached to the component to run every time it is loaded/routed.
all CSS is working fine.

Is there any way to make external script local to component and re-run the script every time it is loaded?

Comment: There is this question of how to dinamically load a script in angular https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34489916/how-to-load-external-scripts-dynamically-in-angular

Answer (score 3):

Sound like a case for [dynamic import expressions](https://mariusschulz.com/blog/typescript-2-4-dynamic-import-expressions). They look like this (quoting the article):

```
import("./widget").then(widget => {
    widget.render(container);
});

renderWidget();
```

Answer (score 0):

A sample is created at 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hadyfy which outlines how script execution can be included only to a desired component (c1 component in the sample).

Let me know if this solves your question.

Essentially the idea here is to get back the basics of loading a script element child to document ==> head element.

```
    ngAfterViewInit() {
let url = "assets/c1.js";  //external script url
let head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
let scrs = head.getElementsByTagName("script");
for(let i=0;i<scrs.length; i++){     
  let scr = scrs[i];

  if(scr.outerHTML.indexOf(url) >0){
    head.removeChild(scr);
  }
}
    let script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = url;
    script.type ="text/javascript";
    script.async = true;
    script.defer = true;
    head.appendChild(script);
```

}

Answer (score -1):

You can try ngZone and run your script outside angular

Answer (score -1):

Try to look into [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34489991/10971586), guy there described how to dynamically download module (js file) and use it, so you can do the same from, for example, `ngOnInit` or `ngAfterViewInit` hook in your component.