# Load external js file in angular app generated by jhipster

Tags: angular, jhipster

How can I load external js file in angular app generated by jhipster like we do usually in angular.json within an angular-cli app.

I have these scripts which should be loaded :

```
 "scripts": [
  "node_modules/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer/assets/pdf.js",
  "node_modules/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer/assets/pdf.worker.js",
  "node_modules/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer/assets/viewer.js"
]
```

and these assets also  :

```
{
    "glob": "**/*",
    "input": "node_modules/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer/assets/locale",
    "output": "/assets/locale/"
  }
```

I already searched a lot for solution and trying many workarounds like using index.html to load that or using vendor.ts or using CopyWebpackPluginlike the:

```
   new CopyWebpackPlugin([
        { from: './node_modules/swagger-ui/dist/css', to: 'swagger-ui/dist/css' },
        { from: './node_modules/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer/assets/locale', to: 'ngx-extended-pdf-viewer/assets/locale' },
        { from: './node_modules/swagger-ui/dist/lib', to: 'swagger-ui/dist/lib' },
        { from: './node_modules/swagger-ui/dist/swagger-ui.min.js', to: 'swagger-ui/dist/swagger-ui.min.js' },
        { from: './node_modules/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer/assets/pdf.js', to: 'ngx-extended-pdf-viewer/assets/pdf.js' },
        { from: './node_modules/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer/assets/pdf.worker.js', to: 'ngx-extended-pdf-viewer/assets/pdf.worker.js' },
        { from: './node_modules/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer/assets/viewer.js', to: 'ngx-extended-pdf-viewer/assets/viewer.js' },])
```

but it's not working. Any ideas ?

Comment: U could do something like that to load external scripts dynammically on specific component:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42766146/7405844

Comment: Have you tried same approach as for the leaflet example in your app's READMEmd?

Comment: i have the same problem but i couldn't find any powerful solution