# how to include js from node modules in Jhipster generated app?

Tags: angular, jhipster

probably a duplicate of this [Load external js file in angular app generated by jhipster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55301730/load-external-js-file-in-angular-app-generated-by-jhipster)

But I have now spent hours trying to find how to do it, but no luck. I primarily use Angular-CLI and this is my first time using Jhipster. Any help is much appreciated.

I am using jhispter version : 6.10.1

Comment: Did you read the instructions from the Leaflet example in your project's README.md?

Comment: I did and I tried that, apparently I did a typo (facepalm). It works for me, thanks !