# May I use binding in <script> tag in html page?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular5

I want to ask if I can use binding between script tags in html page?

I mean

```
<script src="{{SOME_VARIABLE}}"></script>
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Did you try it yourself?

Comment: have you tried?

Comment: @ Mathyn     @ Jota.Toledo   Yes, I have tried,  It does not work

Comment: I don't think it will work, you need add the script explicitly using javascript in components ts file.

Comment: @Kenny Yes I know , I am with you but I only want to check if it is a way

Answer (score 0):

It does not work, because the `script` tags are evaluated before Angular is active. Angular does the binding.

You can lazy load external scripts by using `import()` in your code nowadays. Maybe that helps?

Answer (score 0):

So you want to load scripts dynamically? 
Then this thread should help you [How to load external scripts dynamically in Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34489916/how-to-load-external-scripts-dynamically-in-angular)

And as said before you can't use angular functions or methodes on `<script>`