# Why does javascript not load when changing routes in Angular?

Tags: angular

I am building an Angular application using Angular 8 and I have noticed that when the app first opens up all the components work fine ,but when I change routes the javascript does not load again therefore components on these routes do not work

I have tried the following already:
-Declaring the javascript in the angular.json file.
-Declaring the scripts in the index.html file.

AND

Creating a service to load scripts dynamically:
-https://stackoverflow.com/a/42766146/11067579.

I am calling the above mentioned script loading service as follows in my app.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
import { DynamicScriptLoaderService } from '../app/services/dynamic-script-loader.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})


export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'Look4Cars';

  constructor(private dynamicScriptLoader: DynamicScriptLoaderService) { }




  ngOnInit() {
    'use strict';
    this.startScript();

  }



  async startScript() {

    await this.dynamicScriptLoader.load('jquery', 'jquery.modernizr', 'jquery-ui.min', 'jquery.queryloader2', 'jquery.fancybox', 'mad.customselect',
      'sticky-sidebar', 'query.themepunch.revolution', 'jquery.themepunch.tools', 'owl.carousel', 'mad.tabs',
      'isotope.pkgd.min', 'instafeed.min', 'elevatezoom.min', 'plugins', 'script', 'bootstrap').then(data => {
        console.log('script loaded ', data);
      }).catch(error => console.log(error));
  }
}
```

Below is how I have set up my scripts array in the angular.json file :

```
               "scripts": [
              "src/assets/js/libs/jquery-2.2.4.min.js",
              "src/assets/js/libs/jquery.modernizr.js",
              "src/assets/js/libs/jquery-ui.min.js",
              "src/assets/plugins/jquery.queryloader2.min.js",
              "src/assets/plugins/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.min.js",
              "src/assets/plugins/mad.customselect.js",
              "src/assets/plugins/sticky-sidebar.js",
              "src/assets/plugins/revolution/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min5597.js",
              "src/assets/plugins/revolution/js/jquery.themepunch.tools.min5597.js",
              "src/assets/plugins/owl.carousel.min.js",
              "src/assets/plugins/mad.tabs.js",
              "src/assets/plugins/isotope.pkgd.min.js",
              "src/assets/plugins/instafeed.min.js",
              "src/assets/plugins/elevatezoom.min.js",
              "src/assets/js/plugins.js",
              "src/assets/js/script.js",
              "src/assets/plugins/bootstrap.js"
            ]
```

How would one get the javascript to work when changing routes and going back?

Comment: You should load third party scripts using the `scripts` array in `angular.json`.

Comment: @TheHeadRush , Hi thanks for replying , I tried loading the scripts in the angular.json file ,but it does not seem to work

Comment: Happy to help. Could you edit your post to specifically show what you tried and what the actual results were, including any errors from compilation or in the browser console.

Comment: @TheHeadRush Thanks , I appreciate it .I have been stuck on this for some time . I have edited my post as requested and there are actually no compilation errors in the browser console.