# Angular: How to load external scripts across the application in all the components

Tags: angular, typescript

Script tags:

```
<script src="https://www.test.com/dem0.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.test.com/dem01.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.test.com/dem02.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.test.com/dem03.js"></script>
```

Index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Mobile</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="wsstitle" content="catalog">
  <meta name="wssmlc" content="/us/en/">

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.ico" sizes="32x32">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,300i,400,400i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>

</html>
```

I've few external `<script>` tags and I want to make them available in whole app (should be able to load em whenever my view changed in the browser). If I include them in my index.html `<head>` tag it's only working for the first time when the app initially load but for my case I've to load them whenever the view changed. Including the scripts in the `<body>` tag will be a good practice ??

Comment: Not sure if i understand your question. What's the source of these script tags? If these are some external scripts that you want to make available in whole app, you can include those in index.html

Comment: Yes, those are external scripts and I want to make them available in whole app. If I include them in the index.html head it'll only work when the app initially load.

Comment: You need to encapsulate in a class your access to other libraries Ex: Jquery. Then that class you need to integrate it to the angular pipe line ngOnInit, ngOnchange and so on

Comment: All depends on the behaviour you want

Comment: Would be great if you refer any examples or documents @CarlosE

Comment: @Ramana Did the answers helped you?

Answer (score 1):

Add scripts reference path in angular-cli.json under

```
     "scripts": [
       "../src/assets/scripts/asn1.min.js"
      ],
```

To use it in component .ts file

declare var libraryName: any;

Comment: Updated my question, those are external tags and not referring from local.

Comment: External links can also be referred as same way.

Comment: Would be great if you refer any examples or sample snippet

Comment: @ramakrishna-rk did you tested the possible solution?

Comment: Please check this link.                                   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34489916/how-to-load-external-scripts-dynamically-in-angular

Answer (score 0):

Here is some example that demostrate how integrate Jquery and angular loading jquery from external resource : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e1nf7j

There are other code in the example to demostrate a little separation of angular code and Jquery. You can create a Wrapper class to write whatever you need with your library

The other part is to control your components lifecycle . and the Hooks will do the work executing your external code.

Note: 
You need to control the time it takes to load the external library in order to don't have null references, for that the setTimeout()

I hope it helps