# How to include script to head in angular.json

Tags: javascript, angular, aframe

I would like to import `aframe` in the `<head>` tag using the `angular.json` config as a separate bundle.

Inside `angular.json` I have the script to import from my node_modules:

```
"scripts": [
    "node_modules/aframe/dist/aframe-v1.0.0.min.js"
]
```

This is bundled and imported at the bottom on the html body.

```
<body>
    <app-root></app-root>
    ...
    <script src="scripts.js" ...>
</body>
```

This is not desirable as the library specifically requests that I import in the `<head>`.

Additionally, I would like to import it as a separate bundle:

```
"scripts": [
  { "input": "node_modules/aframe/dist/aframe-v1.0.0.min.js", "bundleName": "aframe-v1.0.0.min" }
]
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

you can add the script reference to angular.json like this as example include jquery library

```js
"scripts": [
   {
    "input": "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "inject": false,
    "bundleName": "jquery"
   }
]
```

then set inject to `false` will not injected the script to index.htm, finaly we just set a name for bundleName this way the script will not bundle with other script file and will be standalone file ,
and now you can add the script tag to the header tag

update the index.html and include the script tag at the header

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Portfolio</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <script src="jquery.js"></script> <!--  -->
</head>

<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I am able to achieve this given my current setup, but the goal is to import the scripts in the `head`.

Comment: why do you want to put the script in the head tag ??

Comment: > the library specifically requests that I import in the <head>.

Comment: I have update the answer simple just set inject to false and you need to update the index.html file and put a script tag to the header

Comment: Thank you! I have tested your solution and it works perfectly.

Comment: @Dan happy to help 

Comment: This is no longer working it says inject is not allowed

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it worked for me while loading jquery

Answer (score 0):

You can use a service to inject it in the head.

This answer can help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/44016611/8573150

Comment: you are right but like this the script will load after the main script is loaded m in my answer the script will place before the main script and will load before it 