# Set Angular 9 Material Google maps key from environment

Tags: angular, google-maps, angular9

We've just upgraded to Angular 9, and itching to shift to @angular/google-maps (besides that @agm is now moaning about version incompatibility).

We have different maps keys per environment, and material does not appear to have a way to set the key in code; only via a script tag:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR-API-KEY" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

...where @Agm allowed config per module.

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53026833/2257623) describes a way of dynamically loading the maps script, but at this stage would rather not upgrade than apply a workaround.

How does one set this key in code, per environment?