# How to load external Javascript in Angular 8 application

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm building an application on Angular 8 and in one of my components I whish to include drag.js which contains the following code:

```
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
     doStuff();
})
```

I've added drag.js to my scripts secction in angular.json

> "scripts": [
>                 "src/assets/scripts/drag.js"
>               ]

And have imported it in Angular view such as:

```
<script src="assets/scripts/drag.js"></script>
```

The problem here is the file isn't served and no code runs when the page loads. Maybe this is not possible. Any help here?

Comment: Where did you add the `<script>` tag? Does this `drag.js` have an option to install using `npm `?

Comment: I added the `<script>` tag on the bottom section of an Angular view. It's custom-made javascript so it's not available via npm.

Comment: What do you mean by angular view? You mean `index.html` or the .html of your component?

Comment: Why don't you call doStuff in your component's ngOninit for instance?

Comment: @Alisson - I mean the component itself.

Comment: @David - If you take a look at the script code, what happens here is a binding when page loads, so idealy the script should run on it's own after beeing loaded.

Comment: Just add the script dynamically then:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/34489916/1160794