# Using a whole hmtl string as template containing css and js

Tags: angular

I get from my API a whole HTML-page as a string, containing css (inline as well as in header) and javascript, looking like this:

```
<script></script>
<style></style>
<div></div>
.
.
.
</html>
```

There are no external files, so just a complete HTML page.

I tried to set the document.innerHtml via a function to the string content, HTML is working more or less in this case, but script parts are obv. ignored.

I also tried to just set the template of a component to the string, but then I get a lot of errors, e.G. *Unexpected character "EOF" (Do you have an unescaped "{" in your template? Use "{{ '{' }}") to escape it.)* (because of the containing js I expect) and a lot of *Unexpected closing tag "span". It may happen when the tag has already been closed by another tag.* (read about this one, I just want angular to don´t touch my string)

In another try, I just created a template with one div, that is then filled by the string. Didn´t work because of sanitation, after adding a bypassSecurityTrustHtml, it worked but the css is completly messed up and all js is just removed.

I know that it´s not the angular way to work, but we have a running software that needs to be migrated to angular and pages are generated by a python engine so I don´t have a real way to change the string before I get it from the api. If there would be a way to read the parts, css, scripts  out of the string and somehow seperatly pass them to the page I would also be content (as long as it doesn´t cost to much performance)

Comment: Not really a solution but you could explore using iframes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would split the problem into two sections, appending the html and css and then adding the javascript.

- First, load the script.

As stated, you are receiving the whole content has a string.
Since you know that the javascript will be between the `<script>...</script>` tags, you can get it usuing regex or other ways.
Once you have the script url you can load it by following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34489916/how-to-load-external-scripts-dynamically-in-angular) stackoverflow or others.

There are several ways to append scripts that can be used in Angular, that stackoverflow contains lots of them.

- Second, create the DOM element from the HTML and CSS string

Similarly to previous, you can extract the HTML and css code. Once done, you can use the [DOMParser Api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) to convert your string to a proper DOM element.

- Third, use the Renderer2 to add the created DOM element

Angular allows the manipulation of DOM elements of an application in a safe way.
This is done with the [Renderer2 API](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2). In particular the [appendChild](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2#appendchild) method allows you to add a DOM element to any other DOM element that you want.
You can use this API to add the content that you received.