# Can't find name when using a declared module in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, types

I am using Angular and I would like to add scriptJS to my project in order to load some script dynamically.

I installed scriptjs

`npm i scriptjs`
`npm install -D @types/scriptjs`

Now, the types are defined like [this](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/f7ec78508c6797e42f87a4390735bc2c650a1bfd/types/scriptjs/index.d.ts)

```
declare module 'scriptjs'{ 
    var $script: $script; 
    export = $script; 
}
```

but when I do

```
$script('blabla.js', function () {})
```

I am prompted with `Can't find name $script`.

I already added other @types package to my project and they are correctly found, but I still struggle when using package that extend the global scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to use it, but I had to import it at the beginning of the file before using it.
`import * as $script from "scriptjs";`

Also, I saw another similar question, and it looks like you can import only the function you need https://stackoverflow.com/a/53026833/14079026

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).