# How to use a js script in only one angular component

Tags: javascript, angular

So ,i'm using a js script to display a widget in my angular component, but i wonder why the widget is displayed in all components  instead of only one.

My `index.html`

```
<body>
<script>my widget script</script>
</body>
```

My ts

```
declare var myWidget: any;
 ngOnInit(): void {
  var result = new  myLivescores.result("<player div ID>", );
  }
```

My template

```
<div id="<player div ID>" ></div>
```

If i place the script in the head ,then the widget is dispalyed before my navbar in all components . Can someone help please !!

Comment: you can use dynamic imports

Comment: How does this work ??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34489916/how-to-load-external-scripts-dynamically-in-angular