# AJAX after fetch, data loads multiply scripts

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

It's a basket (shop) script, im using ajax by scrolling down, 18 new article will appear, there is a button "ADD TO BASKET" to add them on personal account!
The problem is that on the index.php page is this code stored that gets the articles by scrolling, and it works perfect:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var limit = 18;
 var start = 0;
 var action = 'inactive';
 function load_country_data(limit, start) {
  $.ajax({
   url:"include/test_fetch.php",
   method:"POST",
   data:{limit:limit, start:start},
   cache:false,
   success:function(data)
   {
    $('#load_data').append(data);
    if(data == '')
    {
     $('#load_data_message').html("<button type='button' class='btn btn-info'>No Data Found</button>");
     action = 'active';
    }
    else
    {
     $('#load_data_message').html("<img src='logo/loading-more.gif'>");
     //$('#load_data_message').html("<div style='position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; height: 100%; width: 100%; background-color: red;'></div>");
     action = "inactive";
    }
   }
  });
 }
```

The articles are appearing on the website but by pressing "ADD TO BASKET" no action happens, this is fixed too, i have loaded all `<scripts />` and `<links />`, but if i scroll down the currend appeared articles adds perfectly 1x article, but after scrolling down and go back up, add on basket a previously fetched article, it adds me 2x article!
When i go down to the page like after 4 or 5 fetches, and go back up on top to the first fetch, and press "ADD TO BASKET" it adds me 4x article (the same article 4 or 5 times).
After every fetch a script is loading `custom.js` to make the add to basket action possible, and obviously it calls it in one click x times it depends from the fetch time.

Here is the `test_fetch.php` file that will be loaded after the scrolldown:

```
<script src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="catalog/view/javascript/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="catalog/view/javascript/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="catalog/view/theme/OPC080192_1/stylesheet/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="catalog/view/theme/OPC080192_1/stylesheet/megnor/custom.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="catalog/view/theme/OPC080192_1/stylesheet/megnor/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/megnor/custom.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/megnor/jstree.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/megnor/jquery.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/megnor/doubletaptogo.js"></script>
<script src="catalog/view/javascript/common.js" type="text/javascript"></script><link href="http://opencart.templatemela.com/OPC08/OPC080192/OPC1/index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=17" rel="canonical" />
<link href="http://opencart.templatemela.com/OPC08/OPC080192/OPC1/index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=17&amp;page=2" rel="next" />
<link href="http://opencart.templatemela.com/OPC08/OPC080192/OPC1/image/catalog/cart.png" rel="icon" />
//php add basket functions
<script src='assets/js/custom.js'></script>

<?php

// The articles and query
// ...

?>
```

So the fetched data doesent work without all the scripts, but the previous articles are calling same function by adding x times...
My question is how to fetch data without the scripts, i want test_fetch.php to use the script from index.php from where they are called to not repeat the scripts!
Hope i made it clear enough!

Comment: What about make your code **Minimal** and **Reproducible**?

Comment: Okay, but again it needs a script called custom.js in the fetch file, so for the current fetched data it works good it adds 1x article, but previously fetched data it adds 2x on click, if i go more back it adds 3x or 5x article per click, it depents how much fetches are made!

Comment: It simply doesent get anything from index.php :/

Comment: Put the `<script>` and `<link>` tags to your main HTML file. If you then use a [delegated event](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/), there is no need to load the `custom.js` over and  over again. That way the duplicate events should be prevented.