# Delete an untagged text string into <head>

Tags: javascript, html

I've the following HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Títle</title>
        default
        <meta name="description" content="delete a unwrapped text string from <head>"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Hello world!</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I found this article [Remove specific <script> tag in <head> tag by onclick event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14708189/remove-specific-script-tag-in-head-tag-by-onclick-event); but is a solution for wrapped strings and this is a loosely, an untagged one.  What would be the correct javascript to remove it?

Comment: Do you mean that in your code you'd like to delete the text "default" ?

Comment: Yes, exactly!  Something like https://jsfiddle.net/hyances/eb8x4w01/18/  The point is to erase or make it to disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most web browsers will push the text nodes in `<head>` to `<body>`. These text nodes will be a part of the document body, indistinguishable from any other text node.

As it stands currently, I don't see any way to remove this text node from the `<head>`.

Comment: Thanks!  `document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('default', '');` solve it!

Comment: This will remove all occurrences of the word `default` in your page.

Comment: I was wrong, .replace will only target the first match. I apologize for the confusion.